# Visual Studio Shows Tons of JavaScript Errors for an ES6 project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, node.js-tools

I'm using Node.js tools for Visual Studio 2015. All ES6 features under Node.js tools options are turned on. I've tried turning them off too. I've also tried setting JavaScript files not to display syntax highlighting.

Visual Studio displays tons of errors for files containing ES6 JavaScript (the content of the files are actually just fine by ES6 standards).

[image]

Interestingly, if I double click on any of the errors, I get a message

[image]

So, it seems that maybe VS is "double-inspecting" these files...and the second pass fails. Because if I open the file in question from solution explorer, there is no run underlining anywhere in the file?

I've spent a long time troubleshooting this. Is there any way to make Visual Studio work, a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node.js Tools for Visual Studio are you using?  You may just need to update to the [latest version](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).

I had this same problem with version 1.1.31117.00, but I'm not seeing it anymore with 1.2.40726.00.

Comment: I'd recommend to add a link to the official page instead of a direct link to the file (which is more likely to get broken at some point)

Comment: This is fixed by marking the js files at content not compile. It's a bug in visual studio